# How to display Tile Coordinate or Quadkey in QGIS map?

Tags: qgis, tiles, display

I am trying to create the following type of map with QGIS:

[image: Tile Coordinates]

For the zoom level displayed, I want to show the contour of the tiles and the tile coordinates.
What is a quick and simple way to do it ?

QGIS: 3.10